# Evaluation of an expression in Java that contains conditional operator

Tags: java, conditional-statements, expression, evaluation

Have a look to the following java expression:

```
srcVariableValue = 
     ((leftRealValue instanceof Integer) ? ((Integer) leftRealValue) : ((Double) leftRealValue)) 
     + 
     ((rightRealValue instanceof Integer) ? ((Integer) rightRealValue) : ((Double) rightRealValue));
```

When it is executed, if leftRealValue and rightRealValue are Integer, the result is Double.

For instance:

- rightRealValue = 1 type Integer
- leftRealValue = 0 type Integer

Result:

- srcVariableValue = 1.0 type Double

Is this the expected behaviour? Of course, switching to if statement, it works well, the result is of type Integer.

I'm using Java 7

Thanks so much.

Comment: How did you define `srcVariableValue`?

Comment: That depends on how you declared `srcVariableValue` in the first place.
If you did `Double srcVariableValue;` as the definition, then the result will be cast to double

Comment: You cannot cast from `Integer` to `Double` as you did here `(Double) leftRealValue`, please put your right code !

Comment: I would assume as you are using the "primitive" operator `+` both possible outcomes of the condition must be "addable" and as a "double" can hold an int but not the other way around the result of `(leftRealValue instanceof Integer) ? ((Integer) leftRealValue) : ((Double) leftRealValue);` is a `double` - which is interestingly exactly what IntelliJ produces when you "extract" that expression.

Comment: It is best to avoid expressions where you have to consult the JLS to find out what is going on.

Comment: Why do you need the conditional operators? Just add the two numbers.

Comment: Trying to response to all: (1) `srcVariableValue` is defined as Object. (2) I'm sure `leftRealValue` is Double in case of not be Integer: (3) I know this is not the best way, my question is, given the expression, is this the expected value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both primitive operands (`int`, `double`) and wrapper class operands (`Integer`, `Double`) binary numeric promotion will be applied.

```
bnp(int,double)
bnp(Integer,Double)
```

[JLS-15.25](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

It means, first, for the second scenario, an unboxing conversion happens.

```
Integer -> int
Double -> double
```

Then, for both, a widening primitive conversion takes place resulting in a `double`

```
double
int -> double
double = expression ? double : double
```

[JLS-5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

which may be converted further based on the variable you assign the result to.